# Send-MgUserMail with Mail.Send delegate permission

Tags: powershell, graph, azure-active-directory

How do you use Send-MgUserMail when the app registration Mail.Send permission is delegated?

```
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId 'clientID' -TenantId 'tenantID' -CertificateThumbprint 'certthumbprint'
    
    $message = @{
        subject = 'test'
        ToRecipients = @(
                @{
                    EmailAddress = @{
                        Address = "email@email.com"
                    }
                }
            )
        body = @{
            contentType = 'html'
            content = 'hello'
        }
    }
    
    Send-MgUserMail -UserId 'upn_of_user_running_script' -Message $message
```

Error: Send-MgUserMail : The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below**:

[image]

Usually, this error occurs if **required permissions** are not granted.

Please note that, using **`Mail.Send`** **Delegated permission** you can't send mail as this applies only if running in the context of a user.

**To resolve the error,** make sure to grant **`Mail.Send`** **Application permission** and **grant Admin consent** like below:

[image]

***After modifying the permissions, I can send the mail successfully like below without any error:***

[image]

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Unauthorized / token contains no permission when trying to use Microsoft Graph to send email - WhereIsMyAnswer](https://whereismyanswer.com/questions/60678497/unauthorized-token-contains-no-permission-when-trying-to-use-microsoft-graph-t)